# devstack openstack-dashboard not found in /etc

Tags: openstack, shibboleth, devstack, openstack-horizon

I am currently trying to integrate shibboleth IdP with devstack, I am following the method described here: https://github.com/burgosz/openstack-horizon-shibboleth. But in the last step of this process, I need to edit the configuration file of openstack-dashboard (horizon) which was suppose to be in /etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings. But I cannot find this openstack-dashboard folder under /etc. Now the log in page says "Unable to retrieve authorized projects". Do not know where I went wrong. [Dashboard login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zl4e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in devstack kilo the path is /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py.